# VS2008, IIS7 web project, non-admin. When?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, iis-7, windows-vista, uac

What needs to happen before we can open Web Application Projects hosted in IIS7 with Visual Studio 2008 without running as Administrator?  Are we talking about waiting for the next version of Visual Studio?  Are there any existing workarounds?

I think it's implied by the above, but this pertains to Vista.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never is a bad option - pretty much all other development I can do as a non-admin. Its not as if the code under IIS requires admin rights either.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to see an IISAdmin group which grants a developer's user account permission to manage IIS without granting full adminstrator privileges to the entire PC.

Answer (score -1):

My **guess** is never. I think admin rights will always be needed to change websites and virtual directories in IIS.

Comment: You still may be right, but I want to make clear that you still need to run as Admin even after the vitual directory has been created and no further changes are necessary.  Web projects using IIS for hosting simply won't open up in non-admin mode.